# Send array list via ui:param to JSF ui:composition template

Tags: jsf, arraylist, parameter-passing, el, facelets

I know i can use ui:param to pass a string from a composition built upon a template

Like this: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-pass-parameters-to-jsf-2-0-template-file/

Then I can use the parameter in the XHTML for the template file.

Can you send an array?

I.e.

```
<ui:insert name="header" >
   <ui:include src="/template/common/commonHeader.xhtml">

    <ui:array name="tagArray" values="val1, val2, val3" />

   </ui:include>
</ui:insert>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only if your environment supports EL 3.0 (part of Java EE 6 / Servlet 3.0, thus at least Tomcat 8, WildFly 8, GlassFish 4, etc or newer). You can the use the [list construction notation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/4.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-4.0#list-construction) `#{[x,y,z]}`.

```xml
<ui:param name="tagList" value="#{['val1', 'val2', 'val3']}" />
```

If you're not on EL 3.0 yet, then your best bet is using JSTL [`fn:split()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/fn/split.fn) to split a delimited string to an array.

```xml
<ui:param name="tagArray" value="#{fn:split('val1,val2,val3', ',')}" />
```